# boost::transitive_closure() and "error: no matching function for call to ‘vertices(const std::vector<std::vector<long unsigned int>..."

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, transitive-closure

I'm using GCC 4.5.0 with boost 1.48.0 on a Linux machine.

While compiling a source file that uses the boost::transitive_closure() function from boost::graph I'm encountering the same problem as in http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-in-using-Transitive-closure-on-Linux-td2573042.html. 
However in my case, including boost/graph/vector_as_graph.hpp before any other Boost header file doesn't change the situation.

Have someone encountered this before and know how to get around it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody that encounter the same problem as I did:
Thanks to Jeremiah Willcock I got this helpfull reply on the boost-users mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-list/DIfni1Mdd5E):

"Please see if r76868 in the trunk fixes this problem; you can just
download
https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/graph/vector_as_graph.hpp and
put it into your tree."